# Parse - NSNull null analog in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, parse-platform, back4app

How to convert this objective c code to Swift:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Review"];
[query whereKey:@"comment" notEqualTo:[NSNull null]];
```

when I simple put:

```
query.whereKey("comment", notEqualTo: nil)
```

Xcode throw build error:

```
'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type 'Any'
```

Technically I understand that I can't simple put nil there, but I did not found any helpful links with analog `[NSNull null]`

The method I call looks like this:

```
- (instancetype)whereKey:(NSString *)key equalTo:(id)object;
```

Comment: looks like there is a function called `query.whereKeyDoesNotExist("comment")` that fits my needs but looks like there is no analog in swift for `NSNull null`

Comment: I belive you can still use `NSNull()` in Swift.

Comment: `[NSNull null]` is not the same as `nil`. `NSNull` is a special singleton object that was used to distinguish between "no object" and a null pointer.  As Sulthan says you can use it in Swift, but I would say that the alternate where function you discovered is more elegant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `NSNull()` directly to represent the `NSNull` singleton instance.

Comment: thanks! I tried this before you answered and somehow it did not work maybe it was just NSNull without brackets I tried to use